# Is it possible to edit the size of a Sun lamp in Blender 2.8

Tags: light, lighting

I've noticed upon switching the lamp types in the new release candidate for Blender 2.8, that the size property for the Sun type is missing. Is that feature removed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like it's now the *Angle* value:

[image]

Comment: As it should be. Size makes no sense on a light source infinitely far away.

Comment: I'm not sure "angle" is more accurate: I guess it refers to how the rays are deflected by atmosphere conditions, but actually it's not the way we naturally understand "angle" when we hear it, we rather think about the angle of the sun in the 3D view, but this is set by the rotation of the object in the scene, not by this value... But Size was not better it's true...

Answer (score 3):

The sun is not an infinitely far away object with no size clearly. It has a size, and although small, does create slightly fuzzy shadows even in a completely clear atmosphere.

I believe that Angle is referring to the angular size of the sun as seen from the surface of the planet, an average of 0.53 degrees should be accurate enough. You can use the same figure for a Moon light too.

Doing this gives hard shadows close up, that grow less distinct with distance.